# What are the steps to follow to debug memory leak in Jest?

Tags: memory-leaks, jestjs

My tests in Jest seem to be leaking :

[image]
[image]

**What are the recommanded steps to debug that kind of issue?**

I'm new to that kind of problem. As you can see, I have tried passing in [the options documented in Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html) (--forceExit --detectOpenHandles --runInBand --logHeapUsage), but that does not solve my problem.

Comment: For the future, [this article](https://chanind.github.io/javascript/2019/10/12/jest-tests-memory-leak.html) may be useful.

Comment: Wow this looks so helpful !!! I'm really looking forward to testing this.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into that I needed to debug some tests leaking memory and found that taking a Heapdump of the process running the tests was trickier than expected. If you add the `--inspect` flag the cli command it will only inspect the `jest` process.

In order to attach a debugger to your test executer go into `node_modules/jest_worker/build/worker.js` and add the `--inspect` flag to the worker. Jest usually strip the `--inspect` flag.

Use this code:

```
_initialize() {
  const args = process.execArgv.filter(v => !/^--(debug|inspect)/.test(v));
  args.push('--inspect');
  const child = (_child_process || _load_child_process()).default.fork(
    require.resolve('./child'),
    // $FlowFixMe: Flow does not work well with Object.assign.
    Object.assign(
      {
        cwd: process.cwd(),
        env: Object.assign({}, process.env, {
          JEST_WORKER_ID: this._options.workerId,
        }),
        // Suppress --debug / --inspect flags while preserving others (like --harmony).
        execArgv: args,
        silent: true,
      },
      this._options.forkOptions,
    ),
  );
  ...
}
```

Finally run your tests like this:
`node --expose-gc scripts/test.js --env=jsdom --runInBand  --logHeapUsage`
If you have not ejected your `react-scripts` you may have to do that first, the change can be reverted after you're done debugging. `--runInBand` is important else you will get too many workers, jest creates one less worker than you have cores in your computer, so it will be hard to inspect / work with them.

Do not add the `--inspect` flag to the `node --expose-gc scripts/test.js --env=jsdom --runInBand  --logHeapUsage` command since then the jest process will take the default debugger port.

After this step you run your tests and open `Google Chrome`, navigate to `chrome://inspect/` your process will appear in the list of `Remote Targets` and from there you can do memory profiling and take heap dumps of your test process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this looks very helpful : I will look into this and keep you posted.

Comment: For those coming here in 2022 - the path is now `build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js`