# Jest memory leak issue

Tags: testing, jestjs, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am running jest unit and integrations tests on my NodeJS api, I am facing some issue with possible memory leak.
I tried upgrading Jest from 26.3.2 to 27.5.1, but that did not help much.
I took some heap snapshot from chrome console.

Snapshot 1
[image]

Snapshot 2

[image]

Snapshot 3
[image]

Snapshot 4

[image]

From above snapshot I can see that the increase in usage is going very high. But I am unable to understand what's going on wrong.

I see something's up with String, Object and JSBufferData. But not sure what the issue is.

In case of string, I see this:
[image]

Multiple calls/lines for the stringified version of library, but where this comes from and why?

In case of Object:

[image]

The object in screenshot is possibly coming from a library I use `countries-list` this is to get list of countries to find ISO name.

And finally the JSBufferData, which points to something like URLSearchParam, but I am not using anywhere in my application any of the above object/library:
[image]

Stack I use:

NodeJS: 16.14.2
Jest: 27.5.1
jest-searial-runner: 1.2.0

Comment: Where and how are you loading your objects? It looks like you are using the package `xlsx`; are you loading files for tests? Are the file references being preserved across tests?

Comment: @uday8486 did you end up finding the cause of this? I'm also seeing the same thing in my heap with the same modules being loaded over and over again

Answer (score 32):

Me and my team were having a memory leak using jest 29.x and node 18.x. The test suite would run, have a memory leak and make node crash at 2GB of memory usage. Increasing RAM memory allocated to node was not an option, since the test suite would increase in number of tests making it eventually fail, besides, 2GB is already too much.

## Practical Solution

This answer IS NOT a direct solution to the problem, but this turns the problem potentially harmless and we used lots of hours to reach it.

First thing you need to do is to set this config on your `jest.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  workerIdleMemoryLimit: '512MB',
  ...
}
```

I chose 512MB, but choose your value with some space left like `"test_suite_ram_startup + 10 * memory_leak_increase"`. whenever the memory usage reaches this value, jest will restart the worker and clear the memory, impact in the total amount of time required to run the tests are negligible.

This alone itself will never allow your test suite to crash and the problem is pretty much solved.

## Lowering the total amount of RAM used

Now, as important as not making node crash is using reasonable amount of RAM to run your tests. Every consideration from now on decreased the total amount of RAM used in a full run of the test suite.

#### 1. Run jest using this config --expose-gc --no-compilation-cache:

```bash
node --expose-gc --no-compilation-cache ./node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js --logHeapUsage
```

The "logHeapUsage" will log the memory usage so you can check the improvement.

#### 2. SWC as a transpiler

If you are using typescript, use SWC as a transpiler to JS instead of tsjest, it's way faster, saved us tons of memory since the transpilation process was our most memory intensive process.

#### 3. Forcebly call the garbage collector after all tests of a test suite.

```
afterAll(() => {
  global.gc && global.gc()
})
```

This in principle shouldn't be necessary, but somehow jest is not doing it as much as it should. Using this, we reduced the total amount of memory per test suite executed.

#### 4. Find libraries with import * as ...

Some libraries like aws-sdk v2 will try to import everything even if you are using just a tiny fraction of it's code. If you look where the import happens in the lib, everything is imported to a single file, than you import from that file and all that useless stuff sits in your memory. To solve it, just trace the exact location where the asset you want sits and import directly from there. In the case of aws-sdk you can also use aws-sdk v3 which solves this problem.

#### 5. Use tiny libraries.

Sometimes we can't just replace libraries, but changing from class-validator to a tiny library like zod helped.

#### 6. Update your libraries.

In our case updating Prisma ORM from 4.10 to 5.0 made wonders. The new prisma made our test suite run 2.6x faster and use way less memory.

### Final Result

Just so you can take some numbers into perspective. Our test suite would require 1.1GB of RAM on startup, every test suite created a memory leak that increased the total amount of memory in 100MB. Each test suite took 15 - 10s to run. After 10 tests node would crash.

- Implementing 1 made small reductions in total amount of RAM.
- Implementing 4 lowered startup memory usage to 400MB.
- Implementing 3 decreased the memory leak increase to 80MB per test suite.
- Implementing 2 lowered the startup memory to 30MB and lowered memory leak to 60MB per test suite.
- I did not measured or remember 5.
- Implementing 6 lowered the memory leak increase to 14 MB per each test suite executed.

At the end of all of this, each test suite took 2-3s to run.

We went from a crashing test run that would start with 1.1GB of RAM usage and climb 100MB per each test suite to a never crashing one (due to the solution I first stated on the jest config) that would start with 30MB and climb 14MB per each test suite executed. If 512MB was ever reached, it would immediately decrease to 30MB again and start to slowly climb again. Also everything was much faster.

I really hope that helps anyone struggling with that.

Comment: Adding the workerIdleMemoryLimit option to my jest config didn't work for me, but adding it as a command line argument did (in case others also have issues with using jest config)

`--workerIdleMemoryLimit=512MB`


This brought our CI memory usage down from 60GB a run to 5GB.

Comment: Thank you pedro for this amazing write up...

Comment: Thank you for the great response Pedro, it has helped me solve a lot of issues. However , I have not been able to add swc (@swc/jest). I had issues related with a 'SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module'., which i have solved with configuration object of  '@swc/jest':
jsc: {
          target: 'es2020',
          parser: {
            syntax: 'typescript',
            tsx: true,
            decorators: true,
          }
        }
But a second error came up with the templateUrl and styleUrls of my components, as it seems swc is not capable of resolving them.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use --logHeapUsage
From [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli):

> Logs the heap usage after every test. Useful to debug memory leaks.
> Use together with --runInBand and --expose-gc in node.

You can try exposing the garbage collector with --expose-gc and adding

```
afterAll(() => {
  global.gc && global.gc()
})
```

Another option is `jest -w 1` to avoid these memory issues.

> --maxWorkers
> Alias: -w. Specifies the maximum number of workers the worker-pool
> will spawn for running tests. In single run mode, this defaults to the
> number of the cores available on your machine minus one for the main
> thread. In watch mode, this defaults to half of the available cores on
> your machine to ensure Jest is unobtrusive and does not grind your
> machine to a halt. It may be useful to adjust this in resource limited
> environments like CIs but the defaults should be adequate for most
> use-cases.
> For environments with variable CPUs available, you can use percentage based configuration: --maxWorkers=50%

References:
[Cannot find memory leak in my Express.js Jest tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72068051/cannot-find-memory-leak-in-my-express-js-jest-tests)
[My Jests tests are leaking memory, how can I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62885390/my-jests-tests-are-leaking-memory-how-can-i-fix-this)
[What are the steps to follow to debug memory leak in Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53853125/what-are-the-steps-to-follow-to-debug-memory-leak-in-jest)
https://chanind.github.io/javascript/2019/10/12/jest-tests-memory-leak.html